# Test in which ranges the collection of dates aren't overlapping

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, math, momentjs

I wrote a script to render a timeline with a dataset in javascript.
But i have to mark the area's where no info is found (yellow in the image).
I absolutely have no idea how to get the ranges without info in the dataset.
(i use momentjs for date calculations)

Example dataset:

```
data: [
    {id: 1, lane: 1, start: 05-02-2006, end: 09-09-2008},
    {id: 2, lane: 2, start: 01-01-2008, end: 31-07-2010},
    {id: 3, lane: 3, start: 15-12-2013, end: 12-02-2016}
]
```

Example image:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create an new array and fill in the voids, something like this

```
var dates = [];

for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    var now       = data[i],
        thisStart = parseDate(now.start),
        thisEnd   = parseDate(now.end),
        prevEnd   = data[i-1] ? parseDate(data[i-1].end) : null;

    if ( prevEnd && prevEnd <= thisStart ) {
        dates.push({id: i + 0.5, lane: 0, start: prevEnd, end: thisStart});
    }

    dates.push({id : now.id, lane: now.lane, start: thisStart, end: thisEnd});
}
```

and you'll end up with an array like this

```
dates : [
    {id: 1, lane: 1, start: "2006-02-04T23:00:00.000Z", end: "2008-09-08T22:00:00.000Z"},
    {id: 2, lane: 2, start: "2007-12-31T23:00:00.000Z", end: "2010-07-30T22:00:00.000Z"},
    {id: 2.5, lane: 0, start: "2010-07-30T22:00:00.000Z", end: "2013-12-14T23:00:00.000Z"},
    {id: 3, lane: 3, start: "2013-12-14T23:00:00.000Z", end: "2016-02-11T23:00:00.000Z"}
]
```

Note that I marked the object that fills the voids with an id if `.5` and lane `0`, you could do whatever you wanted there, as long as it's recognizable to you when you create the layout.

I also created a `parseDate` function, all it does is parse the dates for you to valid date objects, it's included in the fiddle below

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ks8qd5bj/)

Comment: In my example the dates are ordered but that's not always the case.
A data set like this (below) is also possible:

data: [
    {id: 1, lane: 2, start: 01-01-2008, end: 31-07-2010},
    {id: 2, lane: 1, start: 05-02-2006, end: 09-09-2008},
    {id: 3, lane: 3, start: 15-12-2013, end: 12-02-2016}
]

Comment: Then sort the array by date first.